# User settings/configuration with impersonation

Tags: .net, winforms, impersonation

Is it possible to get [ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134265.aspx) to use the currently impersonated user (when impersonation is being done similar to the code sample for [WindowsImpersonationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx)) - the following being a small extract?

```
using (safeTokenHandle)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Did LogonUser Succeed? " + (returnValue ? "Yes" : "No"));
    Console.WriteLine("Value of Windows NT token: " + safeTokenHandle);

    // Check the identity.
    Console.WriteLine("Before impersonation: "
        + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

    Configuration config;
    //config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
    //Console.WriteLine("Local user config path: {0}", config.FilePath);

    // Use the token handle returned by LogonUser. 
    using (WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
    {
        using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate())
        {

            // Check the identity.
            Console.WriteLine("After impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

            // This line throws exception
            config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
            Console.WriteLine("Local user config path: {0}", config.FilePath);

        }
    }
    // Releasing the context object stops the impersonation 
    // Check the identity.
    Console.WriteLine("After closing the context: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
}
```

If I just add the call inside the impersonated scope, I get an exception thrown:

```
Exception occurred. An error occurred loading a configuration file: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
```

If I also call OpenExeConfiguration before the impersonation block, then the second call (inside the block) doesn't fail, but returns the path for the original user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things that need to happen to make this work:

1. The impersonated user's profile needs to be explicitly loaded using [LoadUserProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - this is not done just by impersonating the user. Note that this API requires that the calling process must have the SE_RESTORE_NAME and SE_BACKUP_NAME privileges.
2. If using a Settings class that inherits from [ApplicationSettingsBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.aspx), then you need to implement a custom [SettingsProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsprovider.aspx) that knows how to load config per-user
3. The [Settings properties by default are cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050734/net-settingsprovider-applicationsettingsbase-caching). You need to customise the getters to force a Reload() each time to ensure the SettingsProvider gets called.

This is a good sample showing how to call the LoadUserProfile API - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125810/A-complete-Impersonation-Demo-in-C-NET